# why my second input value is not set even though I am passing values to it (the swap functionality is work though )

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and was trying to create a basic app to swap two values the swapping part is working but the initial value of the second box is set but for the first one it's working

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function Content(props) {
  const { firstName, lastname } = props;
  const [text1, setText1] = useState(firstName);
  const [text2, setText2] = useState(lastname);

  return (
    <div className="content">
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={function (event) {
          setText1(event.target.value);
        }}
        value={text1}
      />

      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={function (event) {
          setText2(event.target.value);
        }}
        value={text2}
      />

      <button
        onClick={function () {
          // [text1 , text2] = [text2, text1]
          setText1(text2);
          setText2(text1);
        }}
      >
        SWAP
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return <Content firstName={"First Name"} lastName={"Last Name"} />;
}

export default App;
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0EvI.png

Comment: Typo. You pass a `lastName` prop but destructure a `lastname` prop in `Content`. Casing matters in Javascript. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Comment: Don't set `state` using `props` data, consume them directly